# Refactoring two methods with the same logic only differ by operators they use?

Tags: javascript, typescript, refactoring

```
  assertToken(type: TOKEN_TYPES, symbol: string) {
    let isTrue = false;
    if (
      this.tokenizer.getCurrentToken() === symbol &&
      this.tokenizer.tokenType() === type
    ) {
      isTrue = true;
    }

    return isTrue;
  }

  assertNotToken(type: TOKEN_TYPES, symbol: string) {
    let isTrue = false;
    if (
      this.tokenizer.tokenType() !== type ||
      this.tokenizer.getCurrentToken() !== symbol
    ) {
      isTrue = true;
    }

    return isTrue;
  }
```

As you can see here, these two methods did almost the same thing, so how to refactor them to one function?

Comment: add a third argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change second one to be

```
assertNotToken(type: TOKEN_TYPES, symbol: string) {
    return !assertToken(type, string);
}
```

or if you don't want to have two functions you can just delete function assertNotToken and in cases where you used it you can use !assertToken(type, string)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work, since the operator inside the If statement differs. It is an AND in the first method and OR in the second method.

Comment: No this solution is not working correctly, It fails in some conditions. Check the above comment for more.

Comment: and so what? Could you give me an example when it doesn't work, because I am pretty sure it should work correctly.

Comment: Sorry, It is working now. But It wasn't working when both methods operator are AND. If you can can you explain why it is not working when both operators are AND.

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the first function's `if` is the negation of that of the second function ([De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)). So, you could pass a third parameter to identify the assertion type and return `isTrue` or `!isTrue`

```js
assertToken(type: TOKEN_TYPES, symbol: string, isAssertion: boolean) {
  let isTrue = this.tokenizer.getCurrentToken() === symbol 
                && this.tokenizer.tokenType() === type;

  return isAssertion ? isTrue : !isTrue;
}
```

Comment: `tellMeTheTruth(false)` is generally quite a bad idea.

Comment: Nope this is also is not working, the operator inside the methods differ.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye they are negations of each other. One is `A && B` and the other is `!A || !B`(which is same as `!(A && B)`)

Comment: @georg yeah. Oleh's answer is better. I was just giving another option.